# why video conversion from avi to mp4 in php using exec function not working?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

i tried to convert any video type to mp4 on the server because the html video tag dose not support any type except mp4. so i used exec function to convert the video on the server but it is not working.
note : 
exec function is not in the disabled function in php.ini

my code :

```
    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {
      $vidname=$_FILES["vid"]["name"];
      $videotype=$_FILES["vid"]["type"];
      $time = time();
      $vidname2=$time.$_FILES["vid"]["name"];

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["vid"]["tmp_name"], 'videos/' . $time.$_FILES["vid"]["name"]);
      if($videotype!="video/mp4")
      {
          exec("ffmpeg -i videos/$vidname2 -an videos/$vidname2.mp4"); // Convert .avi to mp4
          unlink("videos/$vidname2");
      }
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
            <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="vid">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload">
            </form>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

[image: screen shoot of the code]

Comment: are you sure that `videos` directory is writable?

Comment: yes of course i am sure

Comment: First thing to do is to check the result of [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). If that doesn't tell you enough try [passthru()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) instead. This is assuming you've tested the command on the server directly first. My guess would be that `ffmpeg` can't be located, or the video file itself, but I could be wrong.

Comment: also passthru () not working. i try to chech the result of exec() it is an empty array

Comment: what do you mean by "My guess would be that ffmpeg can't be located"

Comment: Does it work if you run the same command manually, and unscripted in a command-line interface? HTML5 video tag supports H.264 (MP4), H.265 (MP4), Theora (OGG/OGV), and VP9/VP8 (Webm), but it is dependent on the browser.